# How to override a 'group' of pages using Views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a hierarchical taxonomy-based website structure, and I want to use Views to override the taxonomy term pages across each level. For example, if the structure was such (using taxonomy terms):

```
- Food (Vocabulary name)
    - Fruit
        - Red
            - Apple
        - Yellow
            - Banana
    - Meat
        - Lamb
        - Buffalo
```

I want to use a single view with contextual filters for both `Fruit` and `Meat`, and a completely different view with contextual filters for `Red` and `Yellow`, and for `Lamb` and `Buffalo`, because I want them to display data in different ways.

I have managed to create a (page) view that applies to each taxonomy term page by setting the path as `taxonomy/term/%`, but the problem is, that view also applies to the inner pages, which I don't want.

So how can I override the taxonomy term pages **with separate views for each hierarchy level**? Some sort of path filtering, or block views, etc?